# Trying to get this function to show below the content

Tags: functions, filters, content, variables

I'm looking to run a function 'catloop' after the content.
Instead of just placing it below the_content();
I wanted to do it the right way. There is also a social plugin that places some sharing function after all the content that I need to be above, so, I have a higher priority on the filter. 
This is what I have in my functions file:

```
function catloop($content) {
if(is_page_template('page-category.php')) {
    function foo() {

   $term = get_field('category_list');
   $term_id = $term->term_id; 
   $catname = $term->name;

   // assign the variable as current category

    // concatenate the query
$args = 'cat=' . $term_id;

if( $term ): $showposts = 10;
$args = array('cat' => $term_id, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' =>       'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => $showposts,'post_status' => 'publish');
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    echo '<div class="timeline">';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo  the_permalink();
    echo '"><h3>';
    echo the_title(); 
    echo '</h3></a>';

         endwhile; else: 
            _e('No Posts Sorry.'); 
        endif; 
    echo '</div>';

 endif;
    wp_reset_query(); 
}

    $foo = foo;

    $new_content = $foo();
    $content .= $new_content;   
}   
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'catloop',9);
```

It's working but, the problem is that it is placing this above the content. I read in other questions that I need to use 'return' instead of 'echo'
but it breaks. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: `$foo = foo;`? This cannot work.

Comment: Hi Jason,

Whats happening is that you are echoing the result, instead of passing it through the filter, since 'the_content' filter gets called before showing the content. What you could do is to save your content as a string in a variable, then append it to the content as you return it.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I'd not echo the text I'd make it a variable e.g. `$additional_text = ""` then at the end of the function `return $additional_text;`.

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $additional_text = '<div class="timeline">';
    $additional_text .=  '<a href="';
    $additional_text .= the_permalink();
    $additional_text .= '"><h3>';
    $additional_text .= the_title(); 
    $additional_text .= '</h3></a>';
    $additional_text .= '</div>';

 endwhile; else: 
    $additional_text = 'No Posts Sorry.'; 
 endif;
```

Then, when you call the function it's going to get the variable as opposed to writing to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work:

```
function catloop($content) {
if(is_page_template('page-category.php')) {
    function foo() {

   $term = get_field('category_list');
   $term_id = $term->term_id; 
   $catname = $term->name;

// assign the variable as current category


// concatenate the query
   $args = 'cat=' . $term_id;



$args = array('cat' => $term_id, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => $showposts,'post_status' => 'publish');
query_posts($args);


if (have_posts()) :

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
     $perma = get_permalink();
     $title = get_the_title();
     $loopy .= '<div class="timeline"><a href="'. $perma . '"><h3>' . $title . '</h3></a>';



         endwhile; else: 
            _e('No Posts Sorry.'); 
        endif; 


endif;

    wp_reset_query(); 
         return $loopy;
}


    $foo = foo;

    $new_content = $foo();
    $fullcontent = $content . $new_content; 
}   
return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'catloop',9);
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution I would be grateful.
Thanks Pedro Coitinho and sdexp